# jQuery alternative to Flash Mosaic Image gallery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery alternative to the Flash Mosaic FX gallery here 
http://www.flashxml.net/mosaic-gallery.html

I manged to get the images to tile using the Masonry jQuery plugin however  I'm having difficulty trying to keep them tiled when they scale as the user mouse overs them..
I was hoping to see some tutorial on this if available

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at Isotope:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html

Click on the item to grow it and click again to shrink it.